# Line after character added by CSS

Tags: html, css, vb.net, razor

In my CSS I have defined the following:

```
.required:before
 {
    content: "*";
    font-weight: bold;
    color: Red;
 }
```

and the following in my view:

```
   <div class="editor-label required">
        Customer Group
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("GroupId", "")
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.GroupId)
    </div>
```

But when I run the view it puts an astericks but then on the next line the label, I would like them to be on the same line. Any ideas?

Comment: Hello again...*asterisk. Sorry if this feels like harassment. Not my intention. Also, you're spamming questions now :p

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/BCMzW/ it seems already on the same line

Comment: If you are using an * to tell user that something is required, then this is information not style. You will have usability issues.

Comment: The problem is not reproducable from the code posted. Please provide a self-contained example that demonstrates the issue. Something that is not present in the code snippet is causing the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.............................................

HI now define position as like this

do this css

```
.required:before
 {
    content: "*";
    font-weight: bold;
    color: Red;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
 }

.required{
position:relative;
    padding-left:10px;
}
```

adjust left or top according to your design

Comment: Still leaves a line before the two?

Answer (score 0):

Add `display: inline-block;` to both `.required` and `.required:before`:

```
.required, .required:before {
    display: inline-block;
}
```